# ImportError: cannot import name 'AsyncClient' from 'binance.client' error

Tags: python, binance

I am trying to connect the Binance API to my python project but I get an error (I downloaded the Binance api package).

this is the code I wrote:

```
from binance.client import Client

api_key = "myapi"
api_secret = "mysecret"

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

def get_coin_price(symbol):
    ticker = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=symbol)
    if ticker is not None and "price" in ticker:
        return ticker["price"]
    else:
        return None

symbol = "BTCUSDT"
price = get_coin_price(symbol)

if price is not None:
    print(f"{symbol} price: {price}")
else:
    print("error")
```

And this is the error I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'AsyncClient' from 'binance.client'
```

I tried to solve the problem using a lot of resources, but it didn't work, it gives the same error every time.

Comment: Could you add the full error log, aka. stack trace, which shows where the line giving the error is, and the preceding code.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following:

`pip install --upgrade python-binance`

or

`pip3 install --upgrade python-binance`

After updating the library, try running your code again to see if the error persists. If it does, please ensure that you have the correct version of the library installed and consult the library's documentation or support channels for further assistance

Comment: i did what you said but i still get the same error.
I use version 1.0.17 of the library

Answer (score 0):

Try to use binance instead of binance.client.

Also try to cancel and rewrite that line to reload the library, sometimes it just glitch itself.